# Excel - Hide specific slicer item

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

I created a Pivot Table for the year 2021 based on a simple database with i)name; ii)type of payment; iii)payment date.

The thing is, each new year, I want the pivot table to show a column with all "names" even if there is no data on them. For that, I've come to a conclusion that I should add those items in another year (like 2020) and set the pivot table to show items without data.

Now, I've created a slicer to show the years. But 2020 is there (because of the previoulsy entered data to show the "names").

Can I hide just "2020"? This a table that I want to use for years, and 2021, 2022, 2023... I want to be there, but not 2020.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. Maybe it would get a better answer over at  https://superuser.com/

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Comment: Is from another sheet. 3 columns.
I'll try at superuser, thank you!

Comment: Excel is not a database. PowerQuery is based on SQL but if you need a real database you can use Access as your backend. Excel can also query MS SQL Express, a more powerful free option.